# Blur bg with random bg as source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im using Blur.js to create a blurred background in a div with a parent div as its source.

on my parent div I have a small jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var images = ['../img/bg1.jpg', '../img/.bg2.jpg', '../img/bg3.jpg', '../img/bg4.jpg', '../img/bg5.jpg'];
$('#jumbotron').css({'background-image': 'url(../img/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
 });
```

But when I do this, the blur BG does not seem to pick a source.

Anyone can help me with this? :)

Greetings.

Comment: You are adding '../img/' in the images array as well the .css() method try taking the path out of one of them.

Comment: @dowomenfart +1 for your name, but that is not what I mean, the background images do load, but the blurJS script does not pick the source.

Comment: Can I see your blurjs call to the #jumbotron selector? Even better could you make a fiddle?

Comment: Why don't you just use the `filter: blur()` css property to blur images?

Comment: @Persijn because i want the same positioning in my child div als my parent div

Comment: Can you add some images or create a fiddle so i can see what your talking about? bluring images has nothing to do with positioning as far as i iknow.